# Cannot use innerHTML in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web

I want to create an element(li) with and write a string with innerHTML in it and then append it to another element(ul) at last. I have seen that you need to use dangerouslysetinnerhtml function but I don't know how to use it.

**THE ERROR:**

> TypeError: Cannot add property innerHTML, object is not extensible

**MY CODE:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { ActivityIndicatorComponent, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Chatroom extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      UEmail: '',
      DefaultText: 'No contact has been selected.',
      messagebox: '',
    }
}

  visiblechat = () => {
    this.setState({DefaultText: "Contact has been selected."})
  }
 

  startchat = () => {
    var messageul = document.getElementById("messageboxul");
    var messagebox = this.state.messagebox;
    var txt = React.createElement("li");
    txt.innerHTML = messagebox
    messageul.appendChild(txt)
  }

  chatfunc = () => {
   var email = this.state.UEmail
   var emailurl = window.location.href;
   var useremailid = emailurl.substring(emailurl.indexOf("?") + 1);
   firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
   .then(providers => {
  if (providers.length === 0) {
    alert("This email ID doesn't exist. Enter a different Email address")
  }else if(email === useremailid){
   alert("You can't message yourself. Enter a different Email address")
  }else {
    this.visiblechat()
  }
});
  }

  sendMessage = () => {
    var emailurl = window.location.href;
    var useremailid = emailurl.substring(emailurl.indexOf("?") + 1); //User display name
    var message;  //User message
    firebase.database().ref("messages").push().set({ //Save user name and message in reference "messages" in firebase database
        "sender": useremailid,
        "message": message
    });
    return false;
}

  render() {

    var emailurl = window.location.href;
    var useremailid = emailurl.substring(emailurl.indexOf("?") + 1);

    var chatcontainer = {
      position: "relative",
      top: 130,
      left: 8, 
    }
  return (<>
  <Text>Your Email: {useremailid}</Text>
  <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 20, position: "relative", top: 20}}>ENTER THE EMAIL OF WHO YOU WANT TO TALK TO:</Text>
  <View style={{position: "absolute", top: 115, width: "100%"}}>
  <TextInput
          style={{height: 45,width: "100%",borderColor: "gray",borderWidth: 2}}
          placeholder=" Enter Email..."
          onChangeText={UEmail => this.setState({UEmail})}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={this.chatfunc}
          title="Login"
          color="#00B0FF"
        />
        </View>

        <View style={chatcontainer}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold", position:"relative",top:1}}>{this.state.DefaultText}</Text>
        <View style={{position: "relative", top:12}}>
        <ul id="messageboxul">
         <li>hahah</li>
        </ul>
        <div style={{position: "sticky", top: 240,height: 60, width: "100%"}}>
        <TextInput style={{position: "relative", width: "100%", height: "100%"}} placeholder="Enter your message"
        onChangeText={messagebox => this.setState({messagebox})}
        />
        <button style={{position: "relative", width: 243}} onClick={this.startchat}>Send Message</button>
        </div>
        </View>
        </View>
</>);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

Don't worry about the `sendmessage` function and`useremailid` variable, It is not important. I will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTML in React Native unless it's inside a [webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, where to start with this one. There is so much to say here. Most importantly, you cannot use HTML with ReactNative. HTML is exclusively a **BROWSER** markup language. Meaning, you can't use HTML / CSS on the phone at all. So `div`, `li`, `ul`, do not exist in React Native. These are building blocks of the WEB

Because these things do not exist, React Native tries to help you out by provide some building blocks out of the box. You are using some of those buiilding blocks (`Text`, `View`, etc). what you are looking for is something analogous to `li` and `ul`. What you are looking for is possibly the `FlatList` component from ReactNative. You can read more about it [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/using-a-listview). Hope I helped. Best of luck